Outlook graphQL Api reading contacts misses a lot of contacts
I developed a query for Outlook contacts using GraphQL via the API.
However, in the Outlook web interface, you can see that under 'All Contacts' there are many more contacts displayed than those I get through the API query.
The graphQL query considers Default, ContactFolder, ChildFolders, and User. Despite this, the API query only returns about 90 contacts, while under 'All Contacts' in Outlook, you can see that there are about 1000 contacts available.
The Outlook account is running on an Exchange server. When looking at the details of the contacts, it is noticeable that the only difference is that contacts with the identifier V16 are not synchronized, while those with the identifier V12 seem to always be synchronized. It is also not clear whether the contacts that cannot be queried via the API actually come from another source, e.g. from another server.
The question: How can you find out what the issue is?
Could it be a permissions problem with the Exchange server, so that the API cannot query all contacts or directories? There are no error messages. Apparently, the GraphQL query actually only finds about 90 contacts.

AFAIK, Outlook doesn't provide a GraphQL API. If I'm incorrect here, please share documentation, and I can take another look.
What they do provide is a product they call Microsoft Graph, which is built on OData, a Microsoft-driven open source specification for their flavor of REST (note that GraphQL is not REST).
That having been said, let's talk Microsoft Graph and pagination. With OData, to get all results (more than a single page-worth), you have to query one page at a time.
Page 1: $top
Here is a possible query for the first 500 results (I think the max per page is 1000) of "my contacts":
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$top=500

Page 2: $skipToken
If there is a Page 2, The JSON result of page 1 will include a property called @odata.nextLink, which is a URL that includes the same page size and a $skipToken (so you don't have to do the math to figure out how much to $skip when you get to higher number of pages).
{
  ...
  "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=5&$skiptoken=RFNwdAIAAQAAAD8...AAAAAAAA"
  ...
}

So then, for Page 2, just use the URL they gave you:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=5&$skiptoken=RFNwdAIAAQAAAD8...AAAAAAAA

And then, if there is a Page 3, you'll get another nextLink.
This is "Server-Driven Paging".
Page 2 Alternate: $top & $skip
If you wanted to jump straight to Page 2 from scratch -- or if you like doing the math yourself -- you can do that using "Client-Driven Paging", which uses both $top and $skip. This would ALSO give you page 2:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$top=500&$skip=500

